# What's the easiest way to evenly distribute a mesh around a circle/cylinder mesh?

Tags: mesh

I have a cylinder mesh like this:
[image]

And I want to distribute a bunch of rectangular meshes around it evenly. This isn't evenly distributed because I manually duplicated and rotated my rectangular meshes around the cylinder.

[image]

How do I make it even around the cylinder mesh and match the rotation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the 3D cursor at the center of the cylinder (probably the center of your scene so you can simply press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>), choose *Transform Pivot Point > 3D Cursor*:

[image]

Then select the rectangle mesh, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>30</kbd> (if you need 12 duplications) <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (repeat) as many times as needed:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

if you are not sure how many cylinders you need or if you want to have that dynamically/procedurally, you can use this node setup in geometry nodes:

[image]